# Understanding Mercurial merging logic

Tags: mercurial, merge

Let's say `myfile` was modified in two repositories (A and B).  In A we do an `hg pull ../B` which gets us these changesets:

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - A5
        \
          B3 - B4
```

As we have two heads (A5, B4), we do an `hg merge`.

Now if there are conflicts, Mercurial fires up our merge tool (Beyond Compare) and we get three views: left is local, center is parent, and right is 'other'.  Given our structure, would left (local) be A5, center (parent) be A2, and right (other) be B4?

Secondly, what exactly is the logic that Mercurial uses to determine that a merge is required?  Does it see that there are two versions of `myfile` without any children?  And how exactly does it determine that A2 is the parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [Merge Tool Configuration](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration)

> The merge tool is run with an argument list of args with the following variables expanded:
>
> - `$output` expands to the existing file which already contains the version from the first parent - and this is also where the result of the merge ends up / must end up
> - `$local` expands to file.orig which is created as a copy of file in the working directory version - it thus contains the unmerged version from the first parent
> - $base expands to `/tmp/file~base.*` which is created with the version from the common ancestor revision ([**see `hg debugancestor`**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FindCommonAncestorOfRevisions?highlight=%28debugancestor%29))
> - $other expands to `/tmp/file~other.*` which is created with the version from the new second parent revision which the first parent is merged with

(so yes, "left (local) be A5, center (parent) be A2, and right (other) be B4")

[image]

(See "[performing the merge](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html#id353830)")

Comment: Thanks.  And how would Mercurial know exactly which files need to be merged?  In my example would it merge all modified files in the changesets `B3` and `B4`?  And what is the logic Mercurial would use to determine that if a file was modified in `B4` and `A4` that the common parent is `A2`?  Intuitively one can tells this by looking at the graph but I'm curious what exactly is Mercurial's logic to determine this.

Comment: @Marcus: Mercurial only has to compare directory or file SHA1 to se if they differ (and need merging) or not: see http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html#toggle_id353585. Mercurial will go back from parent changeset to parent changeset, starting from the two `HEAD` to merge, until it finds the common ancestor.